# The Dyck Language Correction Problem

Tags: ds.algorithms, dynamic-programming, string-matching

Given a word $w$ over $\{ [, ] \}$, the alphabet of the two square brackets, the Dyck correction problem is to find the shortest sequence of edit operations that would make $w$ a Dyck word, i.e., a word in which the squared brackets are balanced.

I can imagine a few practical applications, but my bibliography search yielded nothing. It looks like dynamic programming though. Any ideas?

Comment: Check: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.08402.pdf

Comment: That's an interesting problem! what about the immediate generalization from Dyck languages to context-free languages, have you looked for literature on that question?

Comment: Or maybe even something easier: what about visibly pushdown languages?

Comment: Btw, might be related: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.08259

Answer (score 6):

The generalized problem, concerning Dyck($s$), for $s$ distinct pairs of parenthesis, was studied by Barna Saha in a paper entitled *The Dyck Language Edit Distance Problem in Near-linear Time*

B. Saha, "The Dyck Language Edit Distance Problem in Near-Linear Time," 2014 IEEE 55th Annual Symposium on Foundations of Computer Science, Philadelphia, PA, USA, 2014, pp. 611-620, doi: 10.1109/FOCS.2014.71.

Indeed, the problem is easy for $s=1$. For $s\ge2$ the exact complexity is not known. The classical techniques for correcting context-free languages are $O(sn^3)$ (Valiant 1975). On the other hand, the usual string editing problem which can be solved in quadratic time can be reduced to Dyck($s$).

Saha's result gives a nearly linear time algorithm that returns an *approximation* of the true edit distance. I am not sure whether this algorithm can produce the edit sequence.

Answer (score 3):

If by "edit operations" you mean single character insertions, deletions, and substitutions then I believe a greedy algorithm works.

Let $x_i$ be the number of ] minus the number of [ in the first $i$ characters. Every edit operation changes each $x_i$ by at most 2. Hence you will need at least $\lceil \frac {\max x_i} 2 \rceil$ operations to correct the word. One way to achieve this is to substitute all the earliest ] for [ and delete one ] if the number is odd.

Finally, you need $x_n$ to be 0. The above operations will reduce $x_n$ by $\max x_i$ and this is unavoidable, since an operation at position $i$ affects exactly those positions after $i$ and by an equal amount. Hence you will need a final $\lceil \frac {\max x_i - x_n} 2 \rceil$ operations to finish correcting the word. One way to achieve this is to substitute the latest [ for ] and delete one [ if the number is odd.

Since the solution is so simple, I doubt there's any literature on it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by saying: "One way to achieve this is to substitute all the earliest ] for [ and delete one ] if the number is odd." Do  you mean this is what you do when xi is positive?

Comment: $\max x_i$ and $\max x_i - x_n$ are always nonnegative so yes.